# Bed temp issue on Guider IIs

Tags: temperature, bed

I have a Flashforge Guider IIs and have been having lots of problems with warping ASA and ABS. The filament's recommended bed temp is 80-100 °C on the ASAk I have wasted kilograms of filament testing every setting in the slice, raft, no raft, brim every layer height imaginable.

I ran the bed at 110 °C and that didn't help. With the fans off, the print would always lift on the front right-hand side so I got my thermal imaging camera and checked the bed. Set at 110 °C the bed had a 3-4 degree variation across its surface and only reached 98 °C. I then preheated it to the maximum setting and the hottest point on the bed was only 108 °C. I resliced the model to 120 °C bed temp and have had no warping since.

My question is: can the bed temp be recalibrated such that the bed gets to the temp indicated on the screen?